# egrep file of txt varibles is removing varibles with spaces

Tags: while-loop, grep

i have a script I use that reads ipaddress or ranges lines in from a txt file and insert them into my iptables. allows me to maintain one list for many servers.  Recently I have been playing with string searches and user-agents stopping bad actors that use scripts that identify themselves using weird names in the useragent that i discover using tcpdump

I am trying to read a file and read each line in and

I am reading a file full of variables using egrep for example

```
JuNXhgCR
sipcli/v1.8
sipcli
friendly-scanner
pplsip
Asterisk PBX
Asterisk PBX 1.6.5
erdfcvqwaszx121
sipvicious
eyeBeam
VaxIPUserAgent
VaxSIPUserAgent/3.1
siparmyknife
VoIP SIP v11.0.0
FreePBX 1.8
Test Agent
```

but when i

```
 egrep -v "^#|^$" x | while IFS= read -r uas
 do
 iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 5060 -m string --string $uas  --algo bm --to 65535 -j DROP
 done <"${_input}"
```

I just get ...  but anything with a space is not passed ?? where is... VoIP SIP v11.0.0 , FreePBX 1.8 , Test Agent ??

```
JuNXhgCR
sipcli/v1.8
sipcli
friendly-scanner
pplsip
erdfcvqwaszx121
sipvicious
eyeBeam
VaxIPUserAgent
VaxSIPUserAgent/3.1
siparmyknife
```

Is there a better way to read and do this?

Comment: You have to quote `"$uas"`, I bet.

Comment: Yes that did it thanks